# Trigger Event on Bootstrap-Vue Component (testing)

Tags: unit-testing, vue.js, bootstrap-vue, vue-test-utils

I am writing tests in a vue app (using Jest). While testing a certain component, I need to trigger a change event on a checkbox (which I am using `BFormCheckbox` for).

When I select the checkbox using the selector the actual checkbox evaluates to (`'.custom-control-input'`), I can get the test below to pass. However, I would like to use the name of the actual component (`BFormCheckbox`), which I feel would be easier to follow. Is there any way to make this work?

```
      it('is triggered by clicking a phase checkbox', () => {
        // I would like to write:
        // const phaseCheckbox = wrapper.find(BFormCheckbox);

        // However, I can only get the following to work:
        const phaseCheckbox = wrapper.find('.custom-control-input');

        // this is true for both selectors
        expect(phaseCheckbox.exists()).toBe(true);

        phaseCheckbox.trigger('change');

        // this fails for wrapper.find(BFormCheckbox)
        expect(togglePhaseSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();
      });
```

Comment: @JesusGalvan thanks! It does seem a little brittle to do it that way - is there anything you do to make it more robust?

Comment: `BFormCheckbox` generates HTML with the hidden checkbox nested inside.  Try this: `const phaseCheckbox = wrapper.find(BFormCheckbox).find('input')`. This will work also when rendered in plain mode, button mode, and switch mode, as you are not tying it to a specific class name.

Comment: You can see how BootstrapVue tests `b-form-checkbox` [here](https://github.com/bootstrap-vue/bootstrap-vue/blob/dev/src/components/form-checkbox/form-checkbox.spec.js).

Comment: Did you import the `BFormCheckbox` component?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the `<input type="checkbox">` is nested inside additional HTML markup (as defined by Bootstrap v4), use the following to access the hidden input:

```js
const phaseCheckbox = wrapper.find(BFormCheckbox).find('input')
```

This will not tie you to using the inner element classname(s), as they do change depending on the rendering style mode of `<b-form-checkbox>` (i.e. default custom checkbox, switch style checkbox, button style checkbox, or plain mode checkbox).

Answer (score 1):

[Jest documentation](https://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/ReactWrapper/find.html) shows examples of how to do as you are asking.

**Component Constructors:**

```js
import Foo from '../components/Foo';

const wrapper = mount(<MyComponent />);
expect(wrapper.find(Foo)).to.have.lengthOf(1);
```

**Component Display Name:**

```js
const wrapper = mount(<MyComponent />);
expect(wrapper.find('Foo')).to.have.lengthOf(1);
```

Comment: RIght, the components can definitely be found on the page. I was just hoping to be able to trigger events directly on them. But Troy's answer above is a good substitute.